# I cant deploy my flask app on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, flask

Im new on heroku and im trying to deploy my app there. But it fails and i receive the following message:

```
   Command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__
   file__='/tmp/pip_build_u21590/matplotlib/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize
, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" inst
all --record /tmp/pip-4IJQX6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-external
ly-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_u21590/matplotli
b
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/
__init__.py", line 185, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/
basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 70: ordinal
not in range(128)

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:salty-oasis-2440.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:salty-oasis-2440.git'
```

And above is my list of requirments:

- Flask==0.10.1
- configobj==5.0.0
- gunicorn==19.1.1
- itsdangerous==0.24
- jinja2==2.7.2
- matplotlib==1.3.1
- networkx==1.8.1
- numpy==1.8.1
- pyparsing==1.5.7
- python-dateutil==2.2
- werkzeug==0.9.4

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: complete_log probably has a unicode character. Try .encode() method at the end check if it works.

Comment: Try to see the encoding of (file) `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Heroku issue. This is a [known issue with `pip`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1137) with an unreleased (as of 26/11/2014) fix. Since you are using Python 2.7, you can [manually patch `pip`](https://github.com/remram44/pip/commit/9626970115e2482e556f48896b7dfdf5e0e00d9e) for now.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your project's working virtualenv type the following command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Note: if you don't have a virtualenv for your project consider creating one for your project and then install all requirements there and run the above command again.

Afterward add the new `requirements.txt` to your project repository and push it to heroku:

```
git commit requrements.txt -m "new one from pip"
git push heroku
```

Comment: This is a good description of how to generate the requirements for a Heroku app but is not an answer to the question. The actual problem is with `pip` (see my answer).

Comment: It seems you are right. I thought OP had edited requirements file manually.